# Logistic predict.glm() function error: factor has new levels

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, error-message

I fit a logistic on three numeric continuous variables, followed by a categorical factor [Y, N].

```
logit2A <- glm(DisclosedDriver ~ VehDrvr_Dif+POL_SEQ_NUM+PRMTOTAL+SAFE_DRVR_PLEDGE_FLG, data = DF, family = "binomial")
```

Fit looks wonderful.

```
Coefficients:
                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -2.204e+00  2.253e-01  -9.782  < 2e-16 ***
VehDrvr_Dif            2.918e-01  1.026e-01   2.845 0.004440 ** 
POL_SEQ_NUM           -1.893e-01  5.617e-02  -3.370 0.000751 ***
PRMTOTAL               1.109e-04  5.526e-05   2.006 0.044804 *  
SAFE_DRVR_PLEDGE_FLGY -7.220e-01  1.633e-01  -4.422 9.76e-06 ***
```

So obviously R took the Safe_Drvr_Pledge_Flg categorical factor variable and placed all 'N' values in reference or intercept as opposed to the listed 'Y'.

Now I want to take my fit and calculate the probabilities that my model determines. And here comes the error:

```
> DF$P_GLM<- predict.glm(logit2A, DF, type="response", se.fit=FALSE)
    Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
factor SAFE_DRVR_PLEDGE_FLG has new levels
```

Umm... no it doesn't, because I just fit the model with the exact same data I'm trying to use for the prediction. What's the problem?

Trying to respond to first comment:
Don't know what you mean. I've got 3500 rows of data... It's a logistic regression on 4 continuous variables and one categorical. The categorical has two values, Y or N. My glm fit give the numbers given. I just want to plug it all back in with the predict function and it gives me that error. Here's the categorical variable:

```
 > DF$SAFE_DRVR_PLEDGE_FLG
 [1] Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y N Y Y N Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y N Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y Y
 [60] Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y N N Y N Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y N Y N N Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y N Y N Y N Y Y Y Y Y N Y
 [119] N Y Y Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y Y Y Y N Y Y Y N Y Y Y N Y Y Y N N Y N N N Y N Y Y Y N N Y Y N Y Y Y Y N N Y Y Y Y N N Y N N
 Levels:  N Y
```

What do you mean by a working example? The fit works. The probability output of the predict function doesn't...

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide a minimal working example? This error is likely to do something intrinsic to the data you are working with, so without a reproducible example you're unlikely to get much help.

Comment: A working example means an example that we can run that also has this error.  This helps us help you more quickly by letting us debug the error on our own systems.  It also makes it more likely for you to find the problem yourself.  If you'd tried to do this, you probably would have tried running on a smaller subset of your data, and it would have worked, and so you would have tried another one, and soon you would have found the problem yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using my magic crystal ball to see the output of `str(DF)`...

Aha! `SAFE_DRVR_PLEDGE_FLG` has another level, `""`,  and that in that same row, one of the other variables is missing.  So it's not using that row to do the fit, but when it tries to construct the data matrix to get the predictions, it can't because the level `""` exists in the data set but not in the model.

You should probably fix your data set before fitting the model, but you can also get the predictions to work by not telling `predict` to use the `DF` data frame; it will then successfully work as it uses the data matrix from the model.  However, this will have fewer predictions than there are rows in `DF` because those rows that were causing trouble were automatically discarded.

Example, based on @smillig's:

```
d <- data.frame(w=rnorm(100),
                x=rnorm(100), 
                y=sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE),
                z=sample(LETTERS[3:4], 100, replace=TRUE) )
d2 <- rbind(d, data.frame(w=1, x=1,y=NA, z=""))
fm2  <- glm(y ~ w + x + z, data=d2, family=binomial)

predict.glm(fm2, d2, type="response", se.fit=FALSE)
# Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
# factor 'z' has new level(s) 

predict(fm2, type="response", se.fit=FALSE)
# No error, this works. However, it has length 100 even though d has 101 rows.
```

Comment: can we use try catch function in R to make the predict function foolproof? I tired to do so, but didn't mange, link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721737/how-to-handle-errors-in-predict-function-of-r

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data, it's difficult to know what's happening. This illustration might be helpful:

```
# Construct dataset to illustrate question
d <- data.frame(w=rnorm(100),
     x=rnorm(100), 
     y=sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE),
     z=sample(LETTERS[3:4], 100, replace=TRUE)
     )
fm  <- glm(y ~ w + x + z, data=d, family=binomial) 
summary(fm)

df.p <- expand.grid(w=d$w, x=d$x, z=c(LETTERS[3:4]))

df.p$pred <- predict(fm, df.p, type="response", se.fit=FALSE)
```

Applying the above to your variables should work. I think that the problem you're encountering is because you need to make a new data set for the predicted values. There are a couple ways to do this. I used `expand.grid()`, but one could also use `data.frame()` (combined with `rbind()` as Aaron has done in his response). One could also just `rep()` along the ranges of values for the continuous variables as well instead of using the values as I have done.

Comment: Strange that a "" value was sneaking through. It's been removed and all is well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while validating my results against a training dataset. I tried these simple steps on my data and it worked. Give it a go and see if it make a difference.

mydata[!complete.cases(mydata),]
mydata<-na.omit(mydata)